# Is there a way to enable bulk edit and quick edit on custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-editor, bulk, quick-edit

When viewing a list of all standard post or pages there are convient quick edit and bulk edit functions to edit author, template, status, dates, etc...

Is there an easy to enable similar quick edit and bulk edit tools on Custom Post types?

For example going to: ../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page select all checkboxes, select edit from drop down, click apply, you get options for Author, Parent, Template, Comments, Status, but none of those show up for ../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=mycustomposttype

Comment: Works just fine with my Custom Post Type. Please provide steps to reproduce(or failing that show the code you're using to register the post type).

Comment: Turns out...  it does all work just fine...  I mistakenly hadn't registered 'author' as a capability of the post type.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it.. glad to hear you tracked down the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `show_ui` and `show_in_menu` are set to `true` when the post type is enabled.  then all the usual post/pages features will be available.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Also, make sure that those features are explicitly declared as by the **CPT** as supported.